# bash replacing special characters in a variable

Tags: bash, ksh

pipe (|) limited text file is transferred from Windows application for processing. While processing there is a special character in the first column in first line of the file.
This is how file looks in notepad before transferring from Windows

```
Sector|Name|Manager|...
```

When I read `IFS='|' read -r -a fields < "/uploads/file_data.txt"`, the first column sector is read as `"ï»¿Sector"` with special characters prefixed.

When i do this `head -1 "/uploads/file_data.txt" | od -c` the value printed is

```
0000000 357 273 277   S   e   c   t   o   r   |
```

I tried `tr -d < //uploads/file_data.txt > /uploads/file_data_temp.txt` but dint help. How do i replace the special characters not only this if any unknown characters are in the file uploaded in future.

Comment: Not related to the specific problem you are seeing, but worth a read: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: pipe (de)limitied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have a "bom" (byte order mark, used on unicode locale based system to specify the "little-endian"/"big-endian" ness of the system

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Thankfully, that one seems to be for the utf-8 locale, which is a good thing if you expect only ASCII 1-177 characters...

You could take it out by interposing a sed that has been forced to use (temporarily) the C locale in order to "see" this:

```
LC_ALL=C sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//'
```

used for example as :

```
incoming program | LC_ALL=C sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' | somecmd
 # or
< incomingfile LC_ALL=C sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' > outputfile
  #  <incomingfile  : will give "incomingfile" content as stdin to sed 
  # then sed modifies only the first line, replacing the BOM with ""
  #    (the rest is not touched by sed and is transmitted as-is)
  #  > outputfile : directs sed output (ie, incomingfile without the BOM) to "outputfile"
```

Comment: it is the byte order mark. The octal values `357 273 277` are `ef bb bf` in hex, that's the UTF-8 encoding of U+FEFF. And their terminal is set incorrectly for UTF-8.

Comment: @olivier-dulac thanks for answering. I tried this `/UPLOADS/File_upload_10-29.txt LC_ALL=C sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' > /UPLOADS/File_FINAL.txt` but it gave me each column names and then command not found. `line 1: ï»¿Sector: command not found`

Comment: @Pat try `LC_ALL=C sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' /UPLOADS/File_upload_10-29.txt`.

Comment: @Pat you forgot the "<" before /UPLOADS/.... , so it tried to execute that file instead of using it as stdin...

Comment: Works perfectly after correcting the syntax.. Thank you both.