# how to remove ï»¿ from Shell script output

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm getting ï»¿ in my shell script output.
can someone please assist as how to remove these ï»¿ special characters from the output

NOTE : I'm storing my output in txt file and sending the output through mail

Comment: stray UTF-8 byte order mark? set your text editor to UTF-8 without BOM encoding. Other suggestions for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%C3%AF-from-the-beginning-of-a-file — it's a common issue, you'll have to locate the source of these BOMs yourself

Comment: Does the answer(s) to this other question answer your question? [bash replacing special characters in a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/675318)/

Answer (score 0):

`ï»¿` in ISO8859-1 is encoded as 0xef 0xbb 0xbf.

```
$ printf %s 'ï»¿' | iconv -t ISO8859-1 | hexdump -C
00000000  ef bb bf                                          |...|
00000003
```

That sequence of three bytes also happens to be the UTF-8 encoding of the U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE no break space character.

```
$ printf %s $'\ufeff' | iconv -t UTF-8 | hexdump -C
00000000  ef bb bf                                          |...|
00000003
```

That U+FEFF character is also used as the *byte order mark* (BOM) in UTF-16. It doesn't make sense in UTF-8, but you still see those in Microsoft text files for instance (see also: [How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230)).

It can also happen when some UTF-16 encoded text is decoded to UTF-8 as UCS-2LE/BE or UTF-16LE/BE instead of UTF-16:

```
$ printf X | iconv -t UTF-16 | iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 | hexdump -C
00000000  ef bb bf 58                                       |...X|
00000004
```

Here, it's either that there is a UTF-8 encoded BOM, and your display device assumes text encoded in ISO8859-1 so renders it as `ï»¿`, or there's been double UTF-8 encoding. That is, text was already UTF-8 encoded, but something thought that was ISO8859-1 and re-encoded it in UTF-8.

In the first case, you should be able to remove the BOM by piping to `dos2unix` which should remove that BOM and fix other problems with Microsoft files. Or you could delete occurrences of that three byte sequence with `sed $'s/\xef\xbb\xbf//g'` (assuming a shell with support for those ksh-style `$'...'`).

In the second case, while you could remove those `ï»¿` with `sed 's/ï»¿//g'`, it's possible that the corruption is not limited to that BOM character, and best would be to reverse the double-UTF-8 encoding by doing:

```
<your-file iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1 | one-of-the-above
```